# Website analytics software where I can download all of my data

Tags: gratis, privacy, analytics

I've launched my first site a couple of weeks ago and I want to monitor the traffic. Is there anybody who can recommend a free alternative to Google Analytics?

What is wrong with Google Analytics: I don't like the way Google look at privacy, so i try to minimize my use of Google products. Additionally, Google Analytics limits exports of my own data to 5000 rows.

Requirements:

- All data can be downloaded as CSV or similar
- Free to use
- Analytics viewable on Web/Android/iOS
- Count hits/sessions per day/month/etc
- Diagrams
- Unique/repeat visitors
- Bounce rate
- Page View Duration
- Click path

Comment: Your question is too broad. It is *you* who determines what you want to know from your site. With that information you can make a list of requirements [to write a good question with](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). But I suggest you do your homework first. Search for [web analytics](https://www.google.com/search?q=web+analytics) or [website traffic analysis](https://www.google.com/search?q=website+traffic+analysis) and if you don't find anything come back here with a detailed question.

Comment: Say what is wrong with Google Analytics

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I doesn't like the way google look at privacy, so i try to  minimize my use of google products.

Comment: And somebody edited my question! So it ended up a little different than intended..

Comment: Since you care about privacy, I added a condition (export) which is good for privacy (reduces vendor lock-in) and hopefully makes your question on-topic. I try to reopen your question.

Comment: @KillerGorilla Welcome to Software Recommendations! You can [edit](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/18549/edit) your question if you feel someone entered something you don't mean that way. But keep in mind the "good question" link Jan Doggen send you in his comment.

Answer (score 2):

I sugest you to use [Piwik](http://piwik.org/).

[image: piwik]

Building on top if what Franck Dernoncourt said:

**Overview**
(from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piwik))

> Piwik is a free and open source web analytics application written by a
>   team of international developers that runs on a PHP/MySQL webserver.
>   Piwik is used by over 1,000,000 websites, 1.2% of all websites, and
>   has been translated to more than 45 languages. New versions of Piwik
>   are regularly released every few weeks.
>
> Piwik tracks online visits to one or more websites and displays
>   reports on these visits for analysis.
>
> **Features**
>
> Piwik displays reports regarding the geographic location of visits,
>   the source of visits (i.e. whether they came from a website, directly,
>   or something else), the technical capabilities of visitors (browser,
>   screen size, operating system, etc.), what the visitors did (pages
>   they viewed, actions they took, how they left), the time of visits and
>   more.
>
> In addition to these reports, Piwik provides some other features that
>   can help users analyze the data Piwik accumulates, such as:
>
> **Annotations** — the ability to save notes (such as one's analysis of data) and attach them to dates in the past.
>
> **Transitions** — a feature similar to Click path-like features that allows one to see how visitors navigate a website, but different in
>   that it only displays navigation information for one page at a time.
>
> **Goals** — the ability to set goals for actions it is desired for visitors to take (such as visiting a page or buying a product). Piwik
>   will track how many visits result in those actions being taken.
>   E-commerce — the ability to track if and how much people spend on a
>   website.
>
> **Page Overlay** — a feature that displays analytics data overlaid on top of a website.
>
> **Row Evolution** — a feature that displays how metrics change over time within a report.
>
> **Custom Variables** — the ability to attach data, like a user name, to visit data.
>
> Piwik also provides features that are not directly related to
>   analyzing web traffic, including:
>
> **Privacy Options** — the ability to anonymize IP addresses, purge tracking data regularly (but not report data), opt-out support and Do
>   Not Track support. In Germany, 13% of .de websites use Piwik because
>   of these options. Scheduled Reports — reports sent regularly by e-mail
>   or text message.
>
> **Log Importing** — a script is also provided that imports data from web server logs. the API — every report is accessible through a web
>   API as well as almost every administrative function. Programs can be
>   created to use this API.
>
> **the Mobile App** — a free mobile app is provided so users can access their analytics data on their phone.
>
> Though not strictly speaking a feature, Piwik also has the
>   characteristic that users are the only people who see their own data.
>   This is a by-product of Piwik being a self-hosted solution. Software
>   as a service solutions (such as Google Analytics) on the other hand,
>   have full access to the data users collect.
>
> Piwik can also be integrated with many third-party apps including
>   CMSes such as WordPress or Drupal, E-Commerce apps such as Magento or
>   PrestaShop, bulletin board systems such as phpBB, and more.
>
> The Piwik community has also created several plugins that can be used
>   to augment Piwik. There are currently 20 third-party plugins.
>
> **Commercial Services**
>
> The team behind Piwik offers some commercial services to go along with
>   the software. These services include yearly support plans, training,
>   managed hosting and general Piwik-related consulting (for
>   installation, system configuration and maintenance, scaling and custom
>   development).

---

Also consider [Alexa Internet](http://www.alexa.com/)

[image: screen shot]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexa_Internet):

> Alexa Internet, Inc. is a California-based subsidiary company of Amazon.com which provides commercial web traffic data. Founded as an independent company in 1996, Alexa was acquired by Amazon in 1999. Its toolbar collects data on browsing behavior and transmits it to the Alexa website, where it is stored and analyzed, forming the basis for the company's web traffic reporting. According to its website, Alexa provides traffic data, global rankings and other information on 30 million websites, and as of 2015 its website is visited by over 6.5 million people monthly.

---

I hope you found this usefull =)

Comment: The question was put on hold as too broad, so I had to add another requirement, could you please check whether your answer still apply? Sorry for the trouble, thanks!

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul edited the answer. I hope it is satisfying now =)

Comment: I would also suggest piwik for your needs. It's easy to setup and have great features and a plugin api too.

Answer (score 0):

[Piwik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piwik) is one of the most commonly used open source website analytics software, it provides pretty much all features Google Analytics has.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**BBclone** will be the best tool suited for you as it is a PHP web counter which is able to display individual logs as well as accumulated data. 
It enables any web site administrator and give very precise view of who visit the website. Its main features include

- reloading,
- hostname resolution,
- blacklist
- proxy workaround